# ClassCastException - JavaScriptObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: javascript, gwt

My GWT app is throwing this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$ cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

When getting the String response of this function via JSNI:

```
public final native String data()/*-{
    return $wnd.getdata();
}-*/;
```

}

Here's the Javascript code:

```
  function getdata(){
    var data = MyObject.data();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
```

I'm logging the data output from Firebug and here's the output (to check if the js function is actually returning something):

> -0.00030517578125,0.00006103515625,0.00115966796875,0.00146484375,-0.00091552734375,-0.000946044921875,-0.001983642578125,-0.003997802734375,-0.005126953125,-0.00360107421875,-0.0032958984375,-0.004119873046875,-0.00433349609375,-0.0023193359375,-0.0008544921875,-0.003448486328125,-0.00347900390625,-0.0054931640625,-0.0067138671875,-0.005279541015625,-0.006072998046875,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is probably `$wnd.getdata().toString();` but maybe you should try `typeof $wnd.getdata()` to see what the type really is -- maybe it's a bug lurking somewhere else.

Comment: its weird typeof shows that the type is "object", from the MyObject function data: function(){
    return this.flashInterface().data().split(";");
  }, but from the Actionscript function it is defined like this : protected function data():String { ... }

Comment: Does Actionscript return real JavaScript strings or just objects which have the same API and therefore *behave* like JavaScript strings?

Comment: So I presumed that the return value is ultimately a String, beside the fact that console.log shows that is a string of comma-separated floating point

Comment: It seems toString is the way  to get the output